# 4 condiciones dentro de un If() y solo falla con una

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

llevo rato tratando de entender porqué me pasa esto pero no logro ver nada. Tengo un Background Maker que básicamente es un gradient en el que se escogen los dos colores y la orientación y además modifica un h3 para mostrar el gradient que escogiste. No se porqué cuando se selecciona el to bottom deja de mostrar en el h3 el "To bottom" a pesar de que el efecto si se aplica en el background pero solo cuando se selecciona bottom se deja de mostrar ¿Alguien por favor me podría ayudar a saber qué tengo mal?

```js
var css = document.getElementById("cssText");
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
var body = document.getElementById("gradient");
var left = document.getElementById("left"); 
var up = document.getElementById("up");
var right = document.getElementById("right"); 
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");


function buttonClicked(e){ 
 if(e.srcElement){
  id = e.srcElement.id;
  setGradient(id);
 }
}


function setGradient(ori){
 console.log(ori);
 if(ori === "left" || ori === "top" || ori === "right" || ori === "bottom"){
  body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to "+ ori + ", " + color1.value + ", " + color2.value +")";
  css.textContent = body.style.background + ";"; 
 }else{
  body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + color1.value + ", " + color2.value +")"; 
  css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
 }
}

left.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
top.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
right.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
bottom.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);

color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
color2.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
```

```css
html{
 min-height: 100%;
}

body{
 font-family: 'Arial black';
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 0.5em;
 top: 15%;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 255, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0));
}

h1{
 font: 600 2em 'Arial black';
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100%;
}

h2{
 font-size: 1em;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 0; 
 width: 100%;
}

#cssText{
 font-size: 0.8em;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 letter-spacing: 0;
}

input[type="color"]{
 border: none;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 cursor: pointer;
}

#arrows{
 max-width: 100%;
 padding: 1em;
}

#arrows button{
 font-size: 1em;
 border: none;
 padding: 4px;
 background: transparent;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#arrows button:active,
#arrows button:focus,
#arrows button:focus:active
{
 background-image: none;
 outline: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
}

#colorPickers{
 padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Gradient Background Generator</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="gradient">
 <h1> Background Generator! </h1>
 <h2>1. Pick colors:</h2>
 <div id="colorPickers">
  <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#00ff00">
  <input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#ff0000">
 </div>
 <h2>2. Pick the direction: </h2>
 <div id="arrows">
  <button id="left">&larr;</button>
  <button id="top">&uarr;</button>
  <button id="right">&rarr;</button>
  <button id="bottom">&darr;</button>
 </div>
 <h2>Current background:</h2>
 <p id="cssText">linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 255, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0));</p>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No había ningún problema, no se me mostraba el "to bottom" porque en el gradient es la opción por defecto si no le indicas nada, por lo que el código lo ignora y lo imprime sin él.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es en los eventListener que agregaste, en la consola te marca el error:
cross-origin frame

En pocas palabras, el event listener está mal redactado, actualmente tienes:

```
left.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
top.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
right.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
bottom.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
```

Cámbialo por:

```
document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
document.getElementById("top").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
document.getElementById("bottom").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
```

Con eso ya tu código funciona bien

Aquí esta el [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jecs9/9zoL4hr8/67/) que muestra como funciona tu código

Que tengas buen día

Comment: ¡Hola! Muchas gracias por la respuesta, en verdad no había ningún problema, no se me mostraba el "to bottom" porque en el gradient es la opción por defecto si no le indicas nada, por lo que el código lo ignora y lo imprime sin él. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, que tengas buen dia.